# Adding specific rows from one CSV file to another and applying specific conditions

Tags: python, csv

I have a CSV file with a column 'Flag' that has 0 and 1 values. My goal is to move all rows with 0 values to another CSV file. This script will be scheduled to run every hour and move rows with '0' values to another file.

So far I wrote the below code:

```
with open("path/to/my/input/file.csv", "rt", encoding="utf8") as f:
reader = csv.DictReader(f, delimiter=',')
with open("/path/to/my/output/file.csv", "a+", encoding="utf8") as f_out:
    writer = csv.DictWriter(f_out, fieldnames=reader.fieldnames, delimiter=",")
    writer.writeheader()
    for row in reader:
        if row['flag'] == '0':
            writer.writerow(row)
```

With @Raghvendra help below by adding 'a+' to my code I'm able to add rows to my output.csv file. However, it adds header row to my output file each time the script runs. Also, how to prevent adding rows with matching ID? Would it be possible to replace rows in my output.csv file where the ID match with ID in input.csv file instead of adding rows with duplicated ID to output.csv?

Would someone be able to help me with this? Thanks in advance!

input file.csv:

```
id       date          data1     data2    flag
1     2020-03-01      mydata    mydata1    0
2     2020-03-02      mydata     mydata    1
3     2020-03-03      mydata    mydata1    0
```

Comment: Your code has `delimiter=','`, but not your example file.

Comment: Also your example file doesn't have `'MyColumn'`, but `flag`. It makes it unnecessarily harder to help if details don't fit together.

Comment: Is the ID an integer value, and if so, what's the range?

Comment: Are there rows changing in the input file from hour to hour, or are rows only added to it? If the latter, can added rows have the same ID than previous ones?

Comment: Hi Armali, the column rows in the input file are changing from time to time, but also rows with new IDs are being added. ID is not integer but a string. Thanks!

Comment: Are the IDs sorted in a way (so that they appear in a reconstructable order), or is their order only determined by their position in the files? Does the order of the rows in the files need to stay unchanged?

Comment: IDs aren't ordered in a specific way (input.csv) and order doesn't really need to stay unchanged in the output.csv. I could always add a line to sort everything by the date column asc/desc at the very end of the script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Now my problem is to prevent adding records with duplicated IDs to my output.csv. I would need to overwrite records with matching IDs instead if possible.

In order to match IDs, we cannot avoid to read the output file.

```
import csv

data = dict()
# first read the output file in (if one exists already)
try:
    with open("output file.csv", encoding="utf8") as f_out:
        for row in csv.DictReader(f_out): data[row['id']] = row
except OSError: pass

# now add the new rows from the input file; rows with existing id are replaced
with open("input file.csv", encoding="utf8") as f:
    reader = csv.DictReader(f)
    for row in reader:
        if row['MyColumn'] == '0': data[row['id']] = row

with open("output file.csv", "w", encoding="utf8") as f_out:
    writer = csv.DictWriter(f_out, fieldnames=reader.fieldnames)
    writer.writeheader()
    for row in data: writer.writerow(data[row])
```

Answer (score 1):

To append new rows to the file rather than overriding the values try using append (`a`) permission on the file instead of write (`w`).

```
with open("/path/to/my/output/file.csv", "a+", encoding="utf8") as f_out:
```

No need of writting `t` as it refers to the text mode which is the default.

Documented [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open):

```
Character   Meaning
    'r'     open for reading (default)
    'w'     open for writing, truncating the file first
    'x'     open for exclusive creation, failing if the file already exists
    'a'     open for writing, appending to the end of the file if it exists
    'b'     binary mode
    't'     text mode (default)
    '+'     open a disk file for updating (reading and writing)
    'U'     universal newlines mode (deprecated)
```

The second part of your question is not so clear. Can you elaborate a little more?

Comment: thank you for your help so far! I tried with 'a+' and was able to add rows instead of overwrite the existing ones in my output.csv file. However, it also added the header row and wouldn't prevent me from adding rows with duplicated IDs. I would need to actually replace rows with matching IDs rather than duplicating them. Would you be able to help with this? thanks!

Comment: To avoid adding header row try removing `writer = csv.DictWriter(f_out, fieldnames=reader.fieldnames, delimiter=",")`

Comment: partly solved this by removing `writer.writeheader()`, but now there are no headers (no problem I could add them separately). Now my problem is to prevent adding records with duplicated IDs to my output.csv. I would need to overwrite records with matching IDs instead if possible.